# How do you SSH into Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, arch-linux

I'm trying to ssh into my arch linux laptop to use all of my terminal commands from my pc, but i cant figure out how to ssh into my laptop or change the setting to allow other connections into the installation. My computer and my laptop are connected to the same network and im using Ubuntu WSL on my pc.

Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: Shoudn't be specific to Arch Linux: Run the `sshd` service, possibly enable the SSH port on the firewall, and that should basically do it. You may try `ssh -v ...`to see what's going on then... Despite of that you should search existing answers before asking questions. Maybe see https://linuxhint.com/arch_linux_ssh_server/

Comment: To log on with your WSL username, you run `ssh LAPTOP` in WSL. LAPTOP is the name or IP address of your laptop. A more elaborate command,  in case you want key-based authentication, could be `ssh -i PRIVATEKEY USER@LAPTOP`, where USER is an account on LAPTOP, and PRIVATEKEY is a private key file that corresponds to USER's public key on the laptop. Note you can also install Putty on Windows and use that to access the laptop. I suggest 
you [edit the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/647346/edit) and report what you have tried as well as the results of your attempts

Comment: The Archlinux wiki is known for its quality. Check out its [OpenSSH](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenSSH#Server_usage) article.

Answer (score 3):

On the computer you want to ssh into:

1. `sudo pacman -S openssh`
2. `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config` --> comment out `KbdInteractiveAuthentication no`
3. `systemctl start sshd.service && systemctl enable sshd.service`
4. `ip -br a | grep UP` --> grab the `<ip_address>` of form `192.168.x.x`
5. `echo $USER` --> This will be the

On the computer you want to connect from:

1. `ssh <user_name>@<ip_address>` --> apply password from the computer you are connecting to.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using OpenSSH. The easiest way would be to use password authentication:

On your Arch Linux laptop, start the SSH daemon:

`systemctl start sshd`

On your Arch Linux laptop, find your private ip address:

`ip route get 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $7}'`

Now, on your Ubuntu PC, connect to Arch:

`ssh <username>@<ip>`

For example, if my username was "michael", and my ip address was "192.165.1.14", I would run:

`ssh michael@192.165.1.14`

Once you're done with your SSH session, you should, on you Arch Linux laptop, stop the SSH daemon:

`systemctl stop sshd`

Comment: contrary to this answer I would recommand to enable and keep ssh service running. In case of any problem, im 98% of all cases, you can still ssh to the PC for a clean shutdown. Also think about enabling the magic sysreq key for the rest 2%